# WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to grab source code for carbon-apimgt:
https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt

Also the source code for product-apim:
https://github.com/wso2/product-apim

I don't want to grab the latest source code I just want to grab the v1.10.0 release for these two repos.

What I do to grab the versions and build is the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt.git
git checkout tags/v5.0.3
cd carbon-apimgt
mvn clean install
```

carbon v5.0.3 builds just fine (I am using Java 7)

I than do this for product-apim:

```
git clone https://github.com/wso2/product-apim.git
git checkout tags/v1.10.0
cd product-apim
mvn clean install
```

product-apim is failing the build on a unit test:

```
Tests run: 325, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Aggregator Module .............. SUCCESS [0.640s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Styles Parent .................. SUCCESS [0.033s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Styles ......................... SUCCESS [1.835s]
[INFO] WSO2 Stratos  API Manager - UI styles ............. SUCCESS [1.908s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Multi Tenant Dashboard ......... SUCCESS [0.709s]
[INFO] WSO2 Stratos  API Manager - Dashboard UI .......... SUCCESS [0.770s]
[INFO] WSO2 AM - Login User Interface .................... SUCCESS [0.668s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Features Parent ................ SUCCESS [0.023s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Features Aggregator Module ..... SUCCESS [0.019s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Styles Features ................ SUCCESS [0.307s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Multi Tenant Dashboard Feature . SUCCESS [0.873s]
[INFO] WSO2 Stratos  API Manager - Features Aggregator Module  SUCCESS [0.018s]
[INFO] WSO2 Stratos  API Manager - Style Features ........ SUCCESS [0.307s]
[INFO] WSO2 Stratos  API Manager - Utils Features ........ SUCCESS [0.694s]
[INFO] WSO2 Stratos  API Manager - Dashboard UI Features . SUCCESS [0.385s]
[INFO] WSO2 Stratos  API Manager - Deployment Features ... SUCCESS [0.237s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - P2 Profile Generation Parent ... SUCCESS [0.017s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - P2 Profile Generation .......... SUCCESS [2:28.018s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - DAS Carbon Application ......... SUCCESS [0.218s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Distribution Parent ............ SUCCESS [0.020s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Distribution ................... SUCCESS [1:06.090s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration Tests .............. SUCCESS [1.279s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration Test Common Module . SUCCESS [0.737s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration Admin Clients Module  SUCCESS [3.246s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration Common Test Module . SUCCESS [2.020s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Test Artifacts Tests ........... SUCCESS [0.993s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - RestFul Backend Module for Integration Tests  SUCCESS [0.944s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - ArtifactDeploymentMonitor WebApp  SUCCESS [6.900s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration Extensions Module .. SUCCESS [1.698s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration UI Pages Module .... SUCCESS [0.714s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration New Test Module .... SUCCESS [0.748s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Based on product backend Test Module  FAILURE [43:38.211s]
[INFO] WSO2 APIManager - Nested Feature Categories ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] API Gateway Manager 1.10.0 ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] API Gateway Worker 1.10.0 ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] API Key Manager 1.10.0 ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] API Publisher 1.10.0 .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] API Store 1.10.0 .................................. SKIPPED
```

Failed Tests:

```
APIM684GenerateApplicationKeyTestCase.generateApplicationKeyWithoutScope:222 Response Code Mismatched expected:<200> but was:<302>
```

Anyone have any clue as to why this is not working?

Comment: Your build is successful, but only some tests are failing. The same test fails continuously?

Comment: Everytime I have been building normally get 1 failure. The above had two but yeah I have built multiple times.

Comment: The test case is failing due to an assertion failure. Response Code Mismatched expected:<200> but was:<302>. Try to Debug this issue by only enabling "APIM684GenerateApplicationKeyTestCase" class and running. You can do this by commenting-out other classes from testng.xml

Comment: Can you confirm that the same test fails always..?

Comment: Yes, it is always this one:
testInvokeAPIAfterChangeAPIEndPointURLWithNewEndPointURL(org.wso2.am.integration.tests.api.lifecycle.ChangeAPIEndPointURLTestCase)  Time elapsed: 0.537 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Response data mismatched when invoke  API  after change the end point URL Response Data,


I am using jdk1.7.0_80 if that helps, it seems to be building properly though it is just this test case is always failing. @Bhathiya

Comment: Can you explain what are you going to do by building the product? If you haven't done any changes to the code which can break this test test case, I believe you can ignore this failre and procede.

Comment: We have not done any changes yet to the source code I am taking it directly from the github and building. Do not want to just ignore the unit tests as we want everything to be working before we start making some changes...

Answer (score 0):

This test case is based on the backend "http://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library". Looks like there's been some changes happened in the backend and due to that the test case is failing.
1. Test cases assets the response status code 200 for the GET http://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library request. But first response is 302 redirection to "http://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library**/**" (with the last "/")
2. Response data is checked if it contains "AcceptanceSampling" but it is not there now.

See:
https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/blob/v1.10.0/modules/integration/tests-integration/tests-backend/src/test/java/org/wso2/am/integration/tests/api/lifecycle/ChangeAPIEndPointURLTestCase.java#L137

As Lakmali mentioned in the comment you can ignore this failure or if you really need to see this passing I would suggest you to do two edits to the test case.

1. Change API2_END_POINT_URL with adding a "/":
   http://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/
   https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/blob/v1.10.0/modules/integration/tests-integration/tests-backend/src/test/java/org/wso2/am/integration/tests/api/lifecycle/ChangeAPIEndPointURLTestCase.java#L56
2. Change API2_RESPONSE_DATA with something available in the response. You can go to http://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/ in your browser and add a word that is already available. Eg: adehabitatHR
   https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/blob/v1.10.0/modules/integration/tests-integration/tests-backend/src/test/java/org/wso2/am/integration/tests/api/lifecycle/ChangeAPIEndPointURLTestCase.java#L55
3. Re run the tests